# Get all instances of character present in cell on row in specific range

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Spreadsheed that looks like this:

[image]

I need to create a map from these values. But I also need each child's parents. The map will be uploaded to a database where the children parent ID will be added based on the parent name from the spreadsheet.

```
=ArrayFormula("{'title':"""&Sheet1!A2:A4&""", 'row': "&ROW(Sheet1!A2:A4)&" 'parents': ['?','?'], 'children': false,},")
```

Using `ROW(Sheet1!B3:B48)` I can get the row number ... so I was thinking of using it together with `A` to scan that row for `x` and where that's found, get the column then using $column1 to get the parent's name. But this is my first time working with spreadsheet functions ...

Edit*

`{'title': 'Child3', parents:['Parent1', 'Parent2', 'Parent3']}`

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the desired outcome?

Comment: See my edit please. I added an example for Child3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this via a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script. To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function MAPPING(input) {
  const parents = input.shift();
  const output = input.map(row => {
    let childParents = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
      if (row[i] == "x") childParents.push(parents[i]);
    }
    return [JSON.stringify({
      title: row[0],
      parents: childParents  
    })]
  })
  return output;
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function as if you were using a regular sheets formula. You just have to provide the appropriate range as an argument (in this case `A1:D4`), as you can see here:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="",,B1:D1&" "&A2:A5)))
```